# Two columns TOC : equal length vs. left then right

Tags: table-of-contents, multitoc

Working on a rather long project I have created a table of contents.

Here is the issue: currently, the end of my TOC is split between each column. But I would like to finish the left side before starting the right side.

Explanation with an example :

How mine is finishing :
[image]

Goal :
[image]

MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}

\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}

\makeatletter
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\contentsname{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\newpage


\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you not the most elegant solution, but you can redefine `\@starttoc` to use `multicols*` instead of `multicols`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}

\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}

\makeatletter
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\contentsname{}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{@multitoc@toc}\and\equal{#1}{toc}}{%
      \begin{multicols*}{\multicolumntoc}%
         \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
      \end{multicols*}%
      }{}%
   }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}
\chapter{Test}

\newpage


\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works really well !

Answer (score 1):

Try this modified version of your MWE

```
% multitocprob.tex  SE 545715

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% PW changes
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cfttocstart}{\twocolumn}  
\renewcommand{\@cfttocfinish}{\onecolumn}
\makeatother

%\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
%\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
% end PW changes

\makeatletter
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\contentsname{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\newpage

%\twocolumn
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Another}
\lipsum[1-4]
%\onecolumn
\end{document}
```

Basically I changed a couple of the `tocloft` internal macros to make the ToC be in two columns and at the end revert to one column mode.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working quite well! There is only was thing : the ToC is now starting on a new page. But that is my fault, my MWE was not well coded, you could not know!

Comment: @Guliup Whenever you swap between `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` LaTeX starts a new page.